# Excluding rows with NAs in column-wise calculations

Tags: r, na

I have the below function:

```
colNames = c(1,4)
myfun = function(a,b){
  test$result = 0.0
  for (i in colNames)
  { 
    test$result = test$result + (test[,i] * exp(-a*test[,i+1]) * exp(b*test[,i+2]))
  }
  return(test$result)
}
```

I am basically trying to multiply 3 columns in a sequence (by performing exp operation on i+1 and i+2th columns and multiplying them with col i) and adding their result to a similar operation done to the next 3 columns.

However, I have several null values and whenever I encounter a row in test[,i] with a null value, I want to exclude it from the calculation and perform the next loop.

I mean rows with null values in test[,i] should not be used in the calculation of test$result. Is there anyway to do this?

Sample data:

```
2   1708.637715 21.30199589 1   408.4464296 19.8614872
1   1708.637715 21.30199589 1   408.4464296 19.8614872
2   1708.637715 21.30199589 1   408.4464296 19.8614872
1   1708.637715 21.30199589 1   408.4464296 19.8614872
6   1708.637715 21.30199589 NA  408.4464296 19.8614872
0   1708.637715 21.30199589 NA  408.4464296 19.8614872
```

My first iteration should run normally, but in the next iteration only columns 1 to 4 have to be used in the addition

Please help

Answer (score 1):

You simply have to filter out any rows with `NA` before you enter the loop. To do that the code would be:

```
test <- test[!apply(is.na(test), 1, any),]
```

So then if you alter the function to:

```
new.myfun = function(a,b){
  test <- test[!apply(is.na(test), 1, any),]
  test$result = 0.0
  for (i in colNames)
  { 
    test$result = test$result + (test[,i] * exp(-a*test[,i+1]) * exp(b*test[,i+2]))  
  }
  return(test$result)
}

new.myfun(1,1)
```

With the output:

```
[1] 1.736616e-169 1.736616e-169 1.736616e-169 1.736616e-169
```

Which is hopefully what you're trying to achieve.

---

You can explicitly iterate through rows (or use apply function):

```
new.myfun = function(a,b){

check.for.na <- function(x,y,z, a, b) {
  if(any(is.na(x), is.na(y), is.na(z))){
    return(0)
  }
  return(x*exp(-a*y)*exp(-b*z))
}

result = rep(0, length(test))
for (ROW in 1:length(test)){
  for (i in colNames)
  {
    check_here_for_na <- check.for.na(test[ROW,i], test[ROW,i+1], test[ROW,i+2], a, b)
    result[ROW] = result[ROW] + check_here_for_na
  }
}  
return(result)
}

new.myfun(1,1)
```

Comment: I get what you are saying.. But I still want to multiply and use the non NA columns for my calculation..In my example, I still want to apply the function for rows 5 & 6, but for cols 1,2,3 (no NAs) and leave out cols 4,5 & 6 since they have NA values

Comment: Couldn't you just code it in the function, and iterate through it rowise? (You can use an apply function), but just to make it clear I've just used a for loop.....see my edit

Comment: Thank you. I initially wrote the code to implement it rowwise but my data is huge with 5000 columns and ~1 million rows. So I moved to column operations to apply the function. But I will still check the execution time for the way u suggested